# Twitter API Stream

Tags: twitter, tweepy, sttwitterapi

I'm using Twitter's API streaming with `tweepy` to track Tweets containing a list of terms. One of the terms I want to track is "BE", which is an acronym of a Portuguese party. The problem is that the listener is given positive signals to all Tweets that contain a `youtu.be` link, like this [one](https://twitter.com/Augustunes/status/1125117050047926272).
How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

There's not a good way to do this with Twitter's API.

Your best option is simply to exclude those Tweets when you're processing them.